# SQL: Table cannot be used twice

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```sql
UPDATE clients 
    SET horas = (SELECT horas FROM clients WHERE id = '%s') + '%s' 
WHERE id = '%s'
```

It's working on my PC using Xampp but my workspace has a different MySQL version, and it's printing out that error, how can I fix it? I've tried google but I am not very good with SQL.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  And learn to pass values into queries using *parameters* not by munging query strings.  Why are you using `+` on a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you intend logic like this:

```
UPDATE clients
SET horas = horas + ?
WHERE id = ?;
```

Note that `?` is a parameter placeholder, so this requires two parameters -- one for `horas` and one for `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the row in UPDATE and the row in SELECT are 2 separate rows:

```
UPDATE clients c1
JOIN clients c2
SET c1.horas = c2.horas + %s 
WHERE c1.id = %s
  AND c2.id = %s
```